# Centering all divs

Tags: html, css

I've been googling for around half an hour and still can't find a solution.

I have a website at the minute, which has quite a lot of divs. All of these have a width of 980px and it looks fine on it's own. My only problem is that if the screen is > 980px then it just appears on the left.

Question: Are there any tags I can put around the code which will center it? I've tried `<center>` and hoping for pot luck but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap them in a container div and give it the same width PLUS:`margin: 0 auto;`

```
<div id="container" style="width:980px; margin:0 auto;">
    ....your divs
</div>
```

Of course move the styling to your CSS file, instead of using inline styling!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have not twiddled with `float` (which forces the element to the side), used absolute positioning (which takes elements out of normal flow), or stopped the element from displaying as a block:

Set `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` or use the shorthand notation (`margin: 0 auto`) (where 0 is the top and bottom margin you want).

Make sure you have a Doctype that triggers standards mode (which you should use for all modern development anyway).

See [this article](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is flat - there are no nested divs then you can inlcude the following in your css file:

```
div { 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Otherwise, just wrap all divs with a `<div id="wrapper"></div>` and put this in the css file:

```
div#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
}
```